# Limits involving rational functions

Tags: calculus, limits, radicals

I am new to calculus and I need to solve this question:

> Find the limit of
> $$\frac{\sqrt{x^2+7}-\sqrt{x^3+3}}{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{2x-1}}$$
> as $x$ approaches $2$.

I tried rationalizing the equation but I always get an expression that returns $0/0$ when I substitute $x=2$ into the rationalized equation. Currently I got

$$(\sqrt{x^2+7}/\sqrt{x^3+x^2+7x+7}-(\sqrt{2x^3-x^2+14x-7})-\sqrt{x^3+3}/(\sqrt{x^4+x^3+3x+3}-\sqrt{2x^4-x^3+6x-3})) $$

but I am not sure how to proceed. I also tried viewing the numerator as f(x) and denominator as g(x) to apply the limit laws but that did not work out as well. Please help me and thanks in advance.

Comment: can you include your current working?

Comment: Hi and welcome to the site! Since this is a site that encourages and helps with learning, it is best if you show your own ideas and efforts in solving the question. Can you edit your question to add your thoughts and ideas about it? Don't worry if it's wrong - that's what we're here for. Here's a quick guide: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question

Comment: Here works, for example, $$\frac{(1+x)^\alpha-1}{x}\to \alpha, x \to 0$$, but needs some evaluation.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g.*, [basic help on mathjax notation](/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5020), [main meta site math tutorial](//meta.stackexchange.com/a/70559) and [equation editing how-to](//math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1773).

Comment: I tried to fix your mathjax, but this is the best I would do. Please edit your post. As of now, it is not clear what that second expression is.

Comment: You could expand each term with the Binomial expansion. That will likely get you to the correct answer, although that might not be the quickest way.

Answer (score 2):

It is 0/0, indeterminate form, so apply L-Hospital: differentiate up and down separately.
Then you get $$L=\lim_{x \to 2} \frac{x/\sqrt{x^2+7}-3x^2/(2\sqrt{x^3+3})}{1/(2\sqrt{x+1})-1/\sqrt{2x-1}}=8\sqrt{\frac{3}{11}}.$$

Answer (score 1):

A good idea when dealing with $\frac 00$ limits with square root is to first rationalize the expression (note: I rearranged order, just so that we have positive quantities).

You got $f(x)=\Big(\sqrt{x^3+3}-\sqrt{x^2+2}\Big)\times\dfrac{\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{2x+1}}{x-2}$

Now it is always easier to figure out limits at zero rather than at a random point, so let substitute $x=2+u$ with $u\to 0$.

$f(u)=\underbrace{\Big(\sqrt{11+12u+6u^2+u^3}-\sqrt{11+4u+u^2}\Big)}_{O(u)}\times\underbrace{\dfrac{\sqrt{3+u}+\sqrt{3+2u}}{u}}_{\sim \frac{2\sqrt{3}}u}$

The first term has $\sqrt{11}-\sqrt{11}=0$, so it is basically something in $O(u)$ and it will compensate the $\frac 1u$ in the second term.

At this point, we can ignore terms of higher degree because they will be negligible, so the limit will be the same than the limit of

$$2\sqrt{3}\times\dfrac{\sqrt{11+12u}-\sqrt{11+4u}}{u}$$

As pointed out in the comment you can use the exapnsion $(1+u)^\alpha=1+\alpha u+o(u)$ or rewrite the expression to make appear $\frac{(1+u)^\alpha-1}u$ as suggested (if you are not comfortable with expansions).

In our case this will results in

$\require{cancel}\dfrac{2\sqrt{3}\sqrt{11}}{u}\Big((\cancel{1}+\frac 12.\frac{12}{11}u+o(u))-(\cancel{1}+\frac 12.\frac 4{11}u+o(u))\Big)=\dfrac{2\sqrt{3}\sqrt{11}}{u}\Big(\frac 4{11}u+o(u)\Big)\to\dfrac{8\sqrt{3}}{\sqrt{11}}$

Answer (score 0):

$$ \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\sqrt{x^2+7}-\sqrt{x^3+3}}{\sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{2x-1}} =$$
$$= \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\big(\sqrt{x^2+7}-\sqrt{x^3+3} \big) \big(\sqrt{x^2+7}+\sqrt{x^3+3} \big)\big(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{2x-1} \big)} {\big( \sqrt{x+1}-\sqrt{2x-1} \big) \big(\sqrt{x^2+7}+\sqrt{x^3+3} \big)\big(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{2x-1} \big)} =$$
$$ = \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\big(x^2+7-\big(x^3+3\big)\big) \big(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{2x-1} \big)} {\big( \big(x+1\big)-\big(2x-1 \big) \big) \big(\sqrt{x^2+7}+\sqrt{x^3+3} \big)} =$$
$$ = \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\big(4+x^2-x^3\big) \big(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{2x-1} \big)} { \big(2-x \big) \big(\sqrt{x^2+7}+\sqrt{x^3+3} \big)} = \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\big(2-x\big)\big(2+x+x^2 \big) \big(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{2x-1} \big)} { \big(2-x \big) \big(\sqrt{x^2+7}+\sqrt{x^3+3} \big)}=$$
$$ = \lim_{x \to 2} \frac{\big(2+x+x^2 \big) \big(\sqrt{x+1}+\sqrt{2x-1} \big)} {  \sqrt{x^2+7}+\sqrt{x^3+3} }=\frac {8 \sqrt {3}} {\sqrt{11}}.$$

Comment: Alright I got it thank you everyone for the help really appreciate it!!!